# how to get the last inserted value into combo box

Tags: vb.net

```
create table departments
(
   dept_id int identity primary key,
   dept_name nvarchar(40)
)

  dim connection as new sqlconnection()
  dim selectQuery as string = "SELECT * FROM departments"
  dim da as New SqlDataAdapter(selectQuery , connection )
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    da.Fill(dt)
    cmb.DataSource = dt
    cmb.DisplayMember = "dept_name"
    cmb.ValueMember = "dept_id"
```

after inserting new department in a form. i want to get the last inserted value of departments in a combo box in another form

Comment: What do you mean by Insert?  inserted into the database?  using a datasource you ar not actually inserting into the cbo.Items collection

Comment: i m displaying the rows with the above code

Comment: after inserting new value in the database, you need to update `.DataSource` of the `ComboBox`

Comment: ignore the code i have written that just displays the data ....... i want a query to retrieve the last inserted value into combo box

Comment: last inserted or last selected in the combobox. Last inserted in the combobox you can retrieve by last index of the items: `combobox.Items(combobox.Items.Count - 1)`

Comment: tnx @Fabio.... its working